# TinyMCE textarea appears inside the editor

Tags: tinymce

I'm applying tinymce to a textarea using jquery.tinymce. but i'm having a problem where the textarea is also appearing inside the editor when it should have been replaced by it instead.

Comment: usually this should not happen. can you post your tinymce configuration and maybe a screenshot?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wfNyu.png the textarea should BE the editor and submit button should be outside too.

Comment: the html https://gist.github.com/807665
the js https://gist.github.com/807669

Comment: i upgraded to the beta version of tinyMCE and that fixed the issue, with the textarea showing up, but any input tags in the form are showing up in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the ID attributes of "textarea" elements.
This will fix appearing a textarea inside the editor.

Answer (score 0):

think in the end i was giving the textarea the same id as another element on the page. A bit of tweaking later it was fixed.